# Apache keepalive ratio

Tags: apache

Many web servers are faster when using keepalive, but of course, 
the client must use this feature AND the user must generate more than one request in a row to be useful.
My question : For my web site, I use Apache, I would like to know how many requests has been done by using the keepalive versus those not using the keepalive.
I looked at the access.log file, but I did not found any clues : Do you know how can I get the information ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eric -- the default log format doesn't contain this info, but there's a %X format string that will tell you the status of the connection.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html

which you can add to a custom log format (also described on that page).  There's another flag, %D which may also help -- measures time to serve the response.

This doesn't exactly tell you what you're looking for - you'll then need to group requests (probably by IP address within a few seconds of each other) so you can see what happened in an individual page load (that is, the html and subsequent requests for other files and assets).

But I can save you some time if you just want to know if keep-alive helps.

If your web page is pure text and contains no links to CSS or Javascript or images then keep-alive won't help.  But that would be very, very unusual.

And, if you have a set of users who are locked in a time capsule, stuck with early versions of Netscape from 1995, then their user agents don't do HTTP 1.1.  If you have users who live in modern times, their browsers support HTTP 1.1, and therefore will do keep-alive.

But actually, adding the additional item to the log is probably a good thing to do to satisfy your curiosity.  I have had many people give me the kind of bland generalization I have provided here, but when I actually measured, found something far different than expected.  So go for it!

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will try the custom log asap